# PlaySound random delay in console application

Tags: c++, console-application

The code bellow plays a rolling sound then proceds to start a casino game. But the sound is delayed in the beginning , then when it's looped it plays well , but then at some times the delay returns. How can i make it conssistent.

```
void rulare()
{

    while (balanta >= pretinitial)
    {

        PlaySound(TEXT("RollSound.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        CreareMatrice();
        CalculLinii();
        InitializareSimboluri();

        balanta -= pretinitial;

        SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 8);
        cout << endl;
        //+ cout<<"Alt + F4 pentru a iesi"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 15);

        cout << "Balanta finala: " << balanta + castig << endl;
        cout << endl;


        if (pretinitial > balanta + castig)break;


        if (castig > 0)
        {



            cout << endl;
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 14);
            cout << "Dublezi? (< sau > pentru a selecta si dupa apasa enter)" << endl;

            cout << "----------                                ----------" << endl;
            cout << "|   NU   |                                |   DA   |" << endl;
            cout << "----------                                ----------" << endl;

            SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 15);
            while (true)
            {
                cin >> keypressed;
                if (keypressed == '<')
                {
                    
                    balanta += castig;
                    break;
                }
                else if (keypressed == '>')
                {
                    dublaj(castig);
                    balanta += castig;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        else
        {


            if (nr == 1) Informatie();
            system("pause");


        }system("cls");
    }

}
```

Or if i can't get it to be consistent what is other good equivalent?

Comment: `PlaySound` is a blunt-force instrument. It's not well-suited to any fine work. You'll likely want to use a multimedia framework (SDL, SFML, etc...) or lower-level Windows audio functions that offer better control.

Comment: @user4581301 So there is no method to avoid the inconsistency (with playsound)?

Comment: There could be, but I've always headed off to smarter libraries for work like this.

Comment: @user4581301 can you give me some helpful links for sdl configuration and use ?

Comment: What toolchain are you using? Many have a package manager that will likely already have SDL already compiled and set up for your tools. That's the best way to perform the installation. If you don't have a modern toolchain and need to download and build yourself, [here are the instructions from the horse's mouth](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/Installation).

Comment: @user4581301 MSVC toolchain i think

Comment: @user4581301 ok so i got it working with this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q06uSmkiqec) . Can you reply the question so i can give you the mark ?